# pass the user's timezone from power app to power automate to create an event

Tags: office-365, power-automate, powerapp

I have a workflow which get called from Power Apps, to create an outlook event:-

[image]

now currently i am hardcoding the time zone, so how i can pass the user time zone from power app to the flow, so the event get created based on the user time zone? and if this is possible , will the time zone be based on the user office 365 profile time zone? or his location/pc time zone?

This is the formula to call the flow from power apps:-

```
    WFHSendInviteToCalender.Run(
        "{  
    ""WFHId"": " & Last(NewWFHEntry).ID & ",
    ""Subject"": ""WFO - " & User().FullName & """,
    ""StartTime"": """ & ThisRecord.SelectedStartTime & """,
    ""EndTime"": """ &  ThisRecord.SelectedEndTime & """,
    ""AllDayEvent"": " & !tgAllDayEvent_1.Value & ",
    ""RequiredEmail"": """ & If(
            IsBlank(varCountryAccountEmail),
            varDefaultCountryAccountEmail,
            varCountryAccountEmail
        ) & """,
    ""Body"": """ &  "  
 Hi,
I am Working from office from " & Text(DateTimeValue(ThisRecord.SelectedStartTime),"hh:mm AM/PM") & " " & (ThisRecord.SelectedDate) & " - " & Text(DateTimeValue(ThisRecord.SelectedEndTime),"hh:mm AM/PM") & " " & (ThisRecord.SelectedDate) & " with full access to email.
<br />
Thank you,
" & User().FullName & "
  " & """
}"
    );
```

Thanks